# Performance tuning under Visual Studio 2013 using threads

Tags: windows, multithreading, performance, visual-studio-2013

I have developed an app to parse a log file under Visual Studio 2013. 
The main parsing loop is run in a worker thread.
I ran the Permormance Wizard (Instrumentation) of VS2013 and saw that both (the worker thread and the UI thread) occupied nearly 50%.
In order to speed up processing I have introduced another worker thread to update the UI based on information I'm getting from the parsing thread.

This improved the amount of processed lines per second. But running the Performance Wizard again, shows that each thread now consumes around 33%.
[image]

I wonder if that is correct?
Am I missunderstanding the whole thing?
Do you have any idea, how I could speed up more?
e.g. by changing from workerthreads to *normal* threads or changing thread priority...

Comment: You would have to have all three threads burning 100% core to get a result like that.  Happens when you write a hot wait-loop, constantly checking if the thread is done yet.  Not correct of course.  You can only improve throughput if the thread can do something else useful after it started a worker thread.

Comment: What is the difference between a "workerthread" and "normal thread"? To me, both are threads and the difference is just how they're used. In any case, you are probably doing something wrong: If your UI thread takes a third of the processing power used overall, that is wrong. I would guess that you update the UI on every miniscule change, which is wrong. It wastes performance for redrawing and causes lock contention. However, without knowing much more about your program, it's impossible to say, therefore I second the vote to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought both thread types vary in their pool. As far as I understood, you cannot change priority on workerthread, while you can on *normal* threads.But I might be wrong.